# error to connect soap server in php

Tags: soap, soap-client, php

i am working on shopping cart project, i need globalpay integration . i got the sample code and run in my localhost it shows me error this.

> Warning: SoapClient::__construct() [function.SoapClient---construct]: SSL: fatal protocol error in C:\wamp\www\exampls\PHP Web Service Sample (Credit Card) 4.0.0\PHP Web Service Sample (Credit Card) 4.0.0\globalpay.inc.php on line 37

i enabled soap server in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you need to install the [OpenSSL extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) for PHP.

Comment: how can i check whether my system has openssl extension or not.

Comment: Look at the contents of your phpinfo()

Comment: OpenSSL support :enabled ,

OpenSSL Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8a 11 Oct 2005 

i found above words in phpinfo();
i think it is enabled. is it enabled or not.

Comment: Well yes, it looks like it is :) What OS, PHP version and web server are you running? Also, it would be useful if you can post the var_dump of the catched SoapFault exception.